# $L_1$ convergence of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Does the sequence $f_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}$ on $(0,1)$ converge in $L_1$?
It converges to zero pointwise and I think it converges in $L_1$ as well since $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}}=2\sqrt
{x}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}-\frac{2\sqrt{2\pi}C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi nx}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+const.$ , where $C(u)=\int_0^u{\cos{\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi x^2\right)}}$ is the Fresnel C integral, but I would like to find a more elemental way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Dominated convergence theorem. $ f_ n$ converges pointwise to $0$ and is bounded by $1/\sqrt x$ which is integrable.

Comment: Ow, that was rather obvious. Didn't see that though. Thanks :)